# How to add a ViewController in containerView programmatically?

Tags: swift, containers

I know how to add a ViewController to a container if using an outlet through interface builder. You just drag an outlet from container to ViewController and boom, everythings all set and done. But when it comes to doing it programatically, I can't find any answer on the net? Can anyone give me a sample code? Thanks in advance.

Let's say I have 2 View Controllers and 1 containerView. First Controller is the parent and inside is the container view and inside the containerView is the secondView Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first add constraints with parent view and container view, then you also need to add constraints to your container controller. Finally you should add the didMoveToParent in the end of setting all the constraints.

The example is as follows, you can do a similar thing in your case.

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
    containerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 10),
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
])
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.leadingAnchor),
    controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.trailingAnchor),
    controller.view.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.topAnchor),
    controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.bottomAnchor)
])
controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

or you can also refer this: https://codedump.io/share/jVuaGlB85VtK/1/how-to-add-a-container-view-programmatically

Comment: I revised my question and title, I think you misunderstood my question, but still I want to thank you for helping me. Please try check my question again sir.

Comment: For the sample you can go through the link

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I'm looking for. But if it's ok with you I'll just accept your answer once I've proven that it works.